# Vmtools - what each package gives

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I found that to make vmtools working I need to install several packages:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-dev
```

What gives each of them?

Comment: The project page seems informative enough to me https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools

Answer (score 1):

Ask the packages (after you've installed then):

```
for pkg in open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools-dev ; do
    dpkg -l $pkg
    dpkg -L $pkg
done | less
```

Before you install them, use the suggestion by @Rinzwind:

https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools